# How to delete data from AuditData table that does not exist any more?

Tags: powershell, delete, auditing

Our auditData table is growing and growing. I was able to delete some data using the powershell script:

`foreach ($site in get-spsite -Limit ALL)
{
    $site.Audit.DeleteEntries("05/01/2013")
    Write-host 'Deleting from ' $site
}`

The problem I have is there seems to be lots of garbage still stored in the table. Sites that have been long deleted from SharePoint are still stored in the table.

How do I delete these short of writing a delete statement in the DB itself?

Answer (score 3):

In short, you can't in a supported method as the API requires a valid SPSite object. The supported way of getting around this is to move all sites to a new content database, then abandon the defunct content database.